# How Do I Architect Out This Relationship

Tags: sql, oop

The best way I can describe this is with an example:

Imagine Many Businesses. In any one business there can be multiple divisions. In each division there can be multiple dept. This would be a series of 1 to many, right?...But now what if a given dept can be elevated to a division or may be a division can be sold off and become its own Business or maybe 2 businesses merger. I need this type of fluid design where, I envision, each entity can easily be moved up or down or in or out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a self referential parent.

```
Table Business [BusinessID, BusinessLevelID, ParentBusinessID]
Table BusinessLevel [BusinessLevelID, Description ]{eg. business, division, dept }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at using either isActive boolean fields or start and end date fields to handle changes.  If Division X becomes Business Y, deactivate the old record and add a new one.  Regarding the associated departments, either do the same thing or update the applicable field depending on your requirements for preserving historical data.

Comment: What about a Tree Structure?